# SoapFault exception, Call to undefined function

Tags: php, soap-client

I have a problem with 'soapClient', the error in log:

```
[Wed Mar 26 20:23:15 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function DB() in /home/optim/DEW/task/Functions.php on line 12
[Wed Mar 26 20:23:15 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to undefined function DB() in /home/optim/DEW/task/client.php:6\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/optim/DEW/task/client.php(6): SoapClient->__call('getClases', Array)\n#1 /home/optim/DEW/task/client.php(6): SoapClient->getClases()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /home/optim/DEW/task/client.php on line 6
```

This code function **getClases()**:

```
public function getClases() {
  $query = "SELECT CLASS, COLOR FROM clases";
  $getDB = DB($query);
  return $getDB;
}
```

The error is in:

```
$getDB = DB($query);
```

I tried to include in the call to the database and it works. This is code:

```
public function getClases() {
  $query = "SELECT CLASS, COLOR FROM clases";
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "dwes";
  $db = "class";
  $pass = "123456";

  $odb = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db, $user, $pass);
  $odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  try {
    $resultClase = $odb->query($query);
  }
  catch (PDOException $p) {
  echo "Error ".$p->getMessage()."<br/>";
  }
  return $resultClase;
}
```

This application worked perfectly before using soap-client. Why it says 'Call to undefined function DB ()'?, Where is the problem?.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

DB is not defined, in the scope of the function getClasses().
You can most likely use PHP's "global".

eg.

```
global $odb;
$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db, $user, $pass);
$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now, in my getClasses() function I can use the global "odb"

```
public function getClases() {
  $query = "SELECT CLASS, COLOR FROM classes";
  $getDB = $odb($query);
  return $getDB;
}
```

Comment: still gives the same problem, I have declared an object: $getDB = new Funciones(); $getDB->DB($query);

and now shows this screen: stdClass Object ( )